# How do I update virtualenv?

Tags: 11.04, package-management, python, apt

I have installed [python-virtualenv[image: Install python-virtualenv]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-virtualenv)
 version 1.4.9 and the latest version is 1.6.1. How do I update to version 1.6.1. Do I have to uninstall version 1.4.9? If so, how do I uninstall it?

<sup>(Crossposted on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500110/how-do-i-update-virtualenv-on-ubuntu))</sup>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
sudo pip install virtualenv --upgrade
```

Comment: Works on OSX too, FWIW.

Comment: sudo pip is not good practice for many reasons...